# How does bash > /dev/tcp/"ip"/"port 0<&1 keep its connection alive?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sockets, tcp

I have created a tcp socket with `/dev/tcp/localhost/9999`.
I have a `nc` listening on port 9999.
When you create a socket with `/dev/tcp`, it usually finishes its connection after data is transferred. But when you create a tcp socket by `bash > /dev/tcp/localhost/9999 0<&1`, it keeps the connection alive waiting for the other side to send data.

I understand that the output of `bash` is sent over `/dev/tcp` but how does it keep its connection alive waiting for the other side to send data?

Comment: To those trying to close this: I think this is still "Bash programming" since the `/dev/tcp/*` functionality is Bash's internal feature and it is sensible to use in scripts.

Comment: Being "sensible to use in scripts" doesn't make it a programming question. Lots of things that can be used in scripts are off-topic here. But I'm prepared to cast a reopen vote if there's a compelling argument.

Comment: @Chris It may not be a programming question, but definitely a software development question.

Comment: @Chris Notice I quoted "Bash programming" because I personally think Bash itself is not a programming language but it is "programming" enough in the context of Stackoverflow as `bash` itself is already an acceptable tag/topic in it.  You are the one to give a compelling argument that it isn't.  By default it should be kept open.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Not _all_ Bash topics are on-topic here: _"This tag is for questions about scripts written for the Bash command shell. For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here. Questions about the interactive use of Bash are more likely to be on-topic on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange or Super User than on Stack Overflow."_

Comment: The socket will be kept open as long as the bash process you just started with output redirected to said socket is running.

Comment: “It usually finishes its connection after data is transferred”: no it doesn’t. It waits for the client to disconnect.